# React native setting/accessing a variable inside a function

Tags: javascript, react-native, scope

I'm trying to set the variables lat and lng to the coordinates returned by the geocoder. I think that lat and lng are accessible from inside the geocoder code where it says Geocoder.getFromLocation(inputWhere).then(...), but then outside of that, it doesn't seem to have set the variables to the geocoder's coordinates. Am I missing something about the variable scope? I've commented what the alerts are returning. I've tested that the geocoder works fine and that the "if" condition is being satisfied. Any help appreciated, thanks!

```
submitData = (inputWhere) => {

var lat = 0;
var lng = 0;

if(inputWhere != '') {
  Geocoder.getFromLocation(inputWhere).then(
   json => { 
    var location = json.results[0].geometry.location;
    alert(lat); // Here it says 0
    lat = location.lat; // 40
    lng = location.lng;
    alert(lat); // Here it says 40
   },
   error => {
    alert(error);
   }
 );
 alert(lat); // Here it says 0
}
alert(lat); // Here it says 0

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Geocoder.getFromLocation() takes time to occur.

You need to wait until it finishes

Comment: how do you do that? I mean, there is a `.then` attached to it.

Comment: That's why you get 40 in 2. `alert`.
But the 3rd and 4th `alert` are outside of the `.then`. They occur right away. They don't wait for `.then`

Comment: ahh yeah, makes alot of sense. Gracias