# React Native Geolocation variables unacessable

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

So here's my problem, I have a react native app I'm working on right now, all of the code works except for the function getLocation(). It works in the sense that it returns a latitude and longitude but for some reason it takes too long and when I run a function that relies on the values, it doesn't run in time when that function is called. Is there any way I could maybe delay the function so it has the latitude and longitude when the getLocation() function returns it?

I did some prior research and this was another stack overflow question that is kind of similar, however they used a different way of getting the location.
[React native setting/accessing a variable inside a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44936229/react-native-setting-accessing-a-variable-inside-a-function)

Any help would be appreciated!

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { ActivityIndicator, ListView, Text, View, Picker } from 'react-native';

export default class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isLoading: true,
            dataSource: null,
            key: "KEY NOT SHOWN BUT WORKS",
            latitude: null,
            longitude: null,
            error: 2
        };
    }


    /**
     * This function gets the current geo location of the device and stores it
     * as Lat and Long coordinates.
     * @private
     */
    getLocation(){
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
            (position) => {
                this.setState({
                    latitude: position.coords.latitude,
                    longitude: position.coords.longitude,
                });
            },
            (error) =>
                this.setState({ error: error.message, latitude: 41.77, longitude: -88.07,}),
            { enableHighAccuracy: false, timeout: 5000, maximumAge: 10000 },
        );
    }

    getAPI(){
        fetch('https://developer.cumtd.com/api/v2.2/JSON/getstopsbylatlon?key='+this.state.key+'&lat='+this.state.latitude.toString()+'&lon='+this.state.longitude.toString())
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((responseJson) => {
                this.setState({
                    dataSource: responseJson.stops,
                    isLoading: false,
                }, function() {
                    // do something with new state
                });
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                //error
            });
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.getLocation();
        this.getAPI();
    }



    render() {
        if (this.state.isLoading) {
            return (
                <View style={{flex: 1, paddingTop: 20}}>
                    <ActivityIndicator />
                </View>
            );
        }
        return (
            <View style={{flex: 1, paddingTop: 20}}>
                <Text>Latitude: {this.state.latitude}</Text>
                <Text>Longitude: {this.state.longitude}</Text>
                <Picker
                    selectedValue={this.state.dataSource}>
                    {this.state.dataSource.map((item, key)=>(
                        <Picker.Item label={item.stop_name} value={item.stop_name} key={key}/>))}
                </Picker>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: The geolocation API is asynchronous, so you'll have to find a way to handle things when that info isn't available yet. There isn't really a way to make it any faster. Moreover, it's very possible that the user denies the location permission request, in which case you'll *never* get the lat/long. So you may as well embrace it and figure out something to display when the lat/long isn't available.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply! I was thinking and thought making a boolean and just have it set to true when it changes the value but then I'd need a loop checking it constantly. Is there a more efficient way to do that?

Comment: It returns a value when the success callback you give to `getCurrentPosition` executes. So you'll need to put dependent code within that callback, OR, you could wrap the `getCurrentPosition` call so that it returns a promise, then use the promise `.then` method. But either way you have to embrace the asynchronicity of it.

Comment: That makes sense! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here is a snack with a proposed solution](https://snack.expo.io/@bacon/react-native-geolocation-variables-unacessable)

Simply move the API call into the `getLocation()`, after the location has been retrieved.
You will want to move towards a more Promise based structure when you integrate Permission handling.

Comment: That solution works! Can't believe it was that simple.